# How to pass Textbox value to Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My View code is as below where I am calling a javascript function on key up event. I want to pass the control value to javascript function.
I tried using 'this' and @this, but it didn't work.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeaveDetailsList[0].LeaveTaken, new {id = "numLeaveTaken1", width = "100", @onkeyup = "checkInp2(this);" })
```

** Edited **
Javascript code:

```
function checkInp2(ControlId) {
    var x = document.getElementById(ControlID).value;
    if (isNaN(x)) {
        document.getElementById("btnSave").disabled = true;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("btnSave").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the javascript function

Comment: @StephenMuecke Code Post edited. Code added.

Comment: So you don't actually want the `id`, you want the value of the control. Are you happy with jquery code?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure your `onkeyup` event should work (even though inline events is not really top of the *best practice* list now days), but not with the current function. Try changing it to:

```
function checkInp2(ControlId) {
   var x = ControlId.value;
   ...
}
```

You're sending `this`, referring to the element that triggered the event, to the function so there is no need to use `getElementById`.

If you instead wanted to get the element explicitly by Id, you could use..

```
document.getElementById('numLeaveTaken1').value; //pure JavaScript 

$('#numLeaveTaken1').val(); //jQuery
```

In this case you can skip `this` all together.

Comment: Oh yes, I have to use ControlId.value instead of document.getElementById. Now it is working.

Comment: @RKh I'm glad! I'll note this here since I didn't mention it in my answer: `this` is referring to the element that triggered the event. So when you send `this`, in your example, you're actually sending a reference to the entire textbox. If you're already using jQuery, this code could be a lot neater though :)

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid polluting your mark-up with behavior and instead use [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Give the textboxes a class name

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeaveDetailsList[0].LeaveTaken, new { @class = "leave-taken" })
```

Then the script

```
var button = $('#btnSave'); // cache it
$('.leave-taken').keyup(function() {
  if(isNaN($(this).val())) {
    button.prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    button.prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

or it could be reduced to

```
$('.leave-taken').keyup(function() {
    button.prop('disabled', !isNaN($(this).val()));
});
```

Note also the controls with can now be style with css - `.leave-taken { width: 100px; }`

Comment: I have to mention CSS classes also. In that case Can we give two classes as: @class = "leave-taken, Yellow" ?